# Observable.Window and .Zip not functioning like I would expect

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to turn an `IEnumerable` into an `IObservable` that delivers its items in chunks one second apart.

```
var spartans = Enumerable.Range(0, 300).ToObservable();

spartans
    .Window(30)
    .Zip(Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)), (x, _) => x)
    .SelectMany(w => w)
    .Subscribe(
        n => Console.WriteLine("{0}", n),
        () => Console.WriteLine("all end"));
```

With this code, the only thing that is printed is "all end" after ten seconds. If I remove the `.Zip` then the entire sequence prints instantaneously, and if I remove the `.Window` and `.SelectMany` then the entire sequence prints one item per second. If I peek into the "windowed" observable inside the lambda passed to `SelectMany`, I can see that it is empty. My question is, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring because of how `Window` works with a count - and this one isn't particularly intuitive!

As you know, `Window` serves a stream of streams. However, with a count, the child streams are "warm" - i.e. when an observer of this stream receives a new window in it's `OnNext` handler, it must subscribe to it before it cedes control back to the observable, or the events are lost.

`Zip` doesn't "know" it's dealing with this situation, and doesn't give you the opportunity to subscribe to each child window before it grabs the next.

If you remove the `Zip`, you see all the events because the `SelectMany` *does* subscribe to all the child windows as it receives them.

The easiest fix is to use `Buffer` instead of `Window` - make that one change and your code works. That's because `Buffer` works very similarly to `SelectMany`, effectively preserving the windows by doing this:

```
Window(30).SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
```

The elements are no longer warm windows but are crystallized as lists, and your `Zip` will now work as expected, with the following `SelectMany` flattening the lists out.

#### Important Performance Consideration

It's important to note that this approach will cause the entire `IEnumerable<T>` to be run through in one go. If the source enumerable should be lazily evaluated (which is usually desirable), you'll need to go a different way. Using a downstream observable to control the pace of an upstream one is tricky ground.

Let's replace your enumerable with a helper method so we can see when each batch of 30 is evaluated:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Spartans()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        if(i % 30 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("30 More!");
        
        yield return i;            
    }
}
```

And use it like this (with the `Buffer` "fix" here, but the behaviour is similar with `Window`):

```
Spartans().ToObservable()
          .Buffer(30)
          .Zip(Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now, 
                                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)),
               (x, _) => x)
          .SelectMany(w => w)
          .Subscribe(
              n => Console.WriteLine("{0}", n),
              () => Console.WriteLine("all end"));
```

Then you see this kind of output demonstrating how the source enumerable is drained all at once:

```
30 More!
0
1
...miss a few...
29
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30 More!
30
31
32
...etc...
```

To truly pace the source, rather than using `ToObservable()` directly you could do the following. Note the `Buffer` operation on the `Spartans()` `IEnumerable<T>` comes from nuget package `Ix-Main` - added by the Rx team to plug a few holes on the `IEnumerable<T>` monad:

```
var spartans = Spartans().Buffer(30);
var pace = Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
       
pace.Zip(spartans, (_,x) => x)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .Subscribe(
        n => Console.WriteLine("{0}", n),
        () => Console.WriteLine("all end"));
```

And the output becomes a probably much more desirable lazily evaluated output:

```
30 More!
0
1
2
...miss a few...
29
30 More!
30
31
32
...miss a few...
59
30 More!
60
61
62
...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get this working with Window, but what about this:

```
var spartans = Enumerable.Range(0, 300).ToObservable();

spartans
    .Select(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => x))
    .Merge(30);
```

Comment: That ends up doing essentially the same thing as the `.Zip`, so one item is emitted every second. I still can't get the `.Window` to work (so that 30 are emitted as a group).

Comment: Oh, "In chunks", I totally missed that part - Fixed

Comment: This approach still has the effect of draining the whole `IEnumerable<T>` immediately, and the elements (within a chunk) are presented in a non-deterministic order. Of course, neither of those were presented as requirements, but such requirements wouldn't be unusual.

Comment: I definitely wanted the `IEnumerable` to be lazy, but forgot to mention that part.